# How can it happened - if case statement throws exception "case else" start working?

Tags: vb.net, exception, switch-statement

It looks like impossible but...

```
    Try
    Select Case command
            Case 1
              smth()
            Case 2
                If Not validSmth() Then
                    Throw New Exception(errMsg)
                Else
                   doSmth()
                End If
            Case 3
                doSmthElse()
            Case Else
                Throw New Exception(errMsg2)
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        ProcessEx()
    End Try
```

Firstly `Case 2` runs. Throws exception. And right after this debugger shows that next processed statement is `Case Else`. Only after `Case Else` throws own exception `Catch` block start working. I've never seen this trick. Why can this happened?

I'm sure the block is entered once (not like this:first enter hit `Case 2` and second hit `Case Else`).

Thanks for any ideas.

### Update:

-To Matt Wilko. Thank you for answering. I've switch to `Strict On` in Options of VS2010 but nothing has changed.   `Command` is variable, not function. Watch tool shows that on each step `Command` is the same ( `Command` = 2).

### Answer

Fixed. Yeeaaaahhh. I simplefy code to

```
        Try
        Select Case 2
            Case 2
                Throw New Exception("123")
            Case Else
                Throw New Exception("345")
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        wtf(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

and change project to Console app. This works as I mention. The fix was in `Release mode`. I was debugging in `Release mode`. When I switch to `Debug mode` everything goes as it should.

Thank everyone for rapid answers.

Comment: What is `command`? Is this Supposed to be `Command()` or do you have another variable/function defined for this? Suggest you switch `Option Strict On` if you haven't already

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried a simple example of what you have shown, but for me it works as expected. When the exception is thrown, execution jumps right to the `Catch` and nowhere else. Output reads "EX:2".

I would set some more breakpoints to make sure you are not entering your code twice. If that fails, restart Visual Studio (sometimes the debugger just gets funky). I don't think its possible for the behavior you are describing to happen.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Command As Integer = 2
    Try
        Select Case Command
            Case 1
                Console.WriteLine("1")
            Case 2
                Throw New Exception("2")
            Case 3
                Console.WriteLine("3")
            Case Else
                Throw New Exception("ELSE")


        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("EX:" & ex.Message)
    End Try

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 I would also suggest making sure that the code has actually built properly. By default Visual Studio will run the last version that successfully built, which is very unhelpful as it will not match the current source code.